# Trying to play sound using the <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h> framework

Tags: objective-c, audio, avaudioplayer

i checked for answers but couldn't find any here is my code..i also logged to see if I'm missing something but both loggs showed up but the sound didn't play...i also imported the 
 framework...i cant figure out what I'm doing wrong I'm a newbie please help...Thanks

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    NSLog(@"play!");

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"Submarine" ofType:@"mp3"];
    AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
    [audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
    [audioPlayer play];

    NSLog(@"not playing!");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ARC will decrease the retain count of `audioPlayer` as soon as `viewDidLoad` finishes executing.
Declare `audioPlayer` as an instance variable, then assign in `viewDidLoad` to solve this issue.